# How to link ActionListener to be listened globally?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, jtextarea

I am trying to make simple console based Swing GUI that separates the order and the responses. What I want to do is to make sequential dialogue-like console. For example, player would be asked to type "game" to start and then type players' names to save and goes on. I was successful in making console but don't know how to link user typing information to action listeners.

What I have done are as follows.

```
public class ConsolePane extends JPanel {

    private final JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
    private final JTextArea textAreaOrder = new JTextArea(20, 30);
    private ActionListener listener;
    private JButton button;

    public ConsolePane(ActionListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public JComponent display() {
        textAreaOrder.setText("Game or Exit");
        try {
            OutputStream os = new StreamWriter(textAreaOrder);
            System.setOut(new PrintStream(os, true, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        Box box = Box.createHorizontalBox();
        box.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        box.add(textField);
        box.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        button = new JButton("Enter");
        button.setActionCommand("Enter");
        button.addActionListener(listener);
        box.add(button);
        textAreaOrder.setEditable(false);

        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        p.add(new JScrollPane(textAreaOrder));
        p.add(box, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        return p;
    }
}
```

and

`````
public class Controller implements ActionListener {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextArea textAreaOrder;
    private MainController mc;
    private SetUpController suc;
    private GameController gc;
    private LoadFileUtil fu;
    private ActionListener listener;

    public Controller() {
//        ProcExec instance = new ProcExec(this);
//        EventQueue.invokeLater(instance);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }
                createFrame();
            }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        mc = new MainController(frame, this);
        suc = new SetUpController(frame, this);
        gc = new GameController(frame, this);
        suc.start();
    }

    public void createFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hannah's Mafia Game");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new ConsolePane(listener).display());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

   
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String name = textField.getText();
        switch(name) {
            case "game":
                textAreaOrder.setText("Type players");
                //instance.run();
                break;
            case "exit":
                textAreaOrder.setText("Game Done");
                //instance.run();
                break;
        }
    }

}````
`````

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your code, and your `textfield` exist `ConsolePane` class and `Controller` class -> they're different. Make a `get()` method in `ConsolePane` class to get a text entered to this `JTextField`.

Try make this method in `ConsolePane`:

```
public String getJTextField(){
    return textField.getText();
}
```

Then replace:

`String name = textField.getText();` -----> `String name = getJTextField();`

Comment: To be logically named: `public String getJTextField()` should be either `public String getTextFromField()` or `public JTextField getJTextField()`. And while the latter does not fit the problem context, it should also be more descriptive - something like `public JTextField getFirstNameField()`. Following that same philosophy would mean `getFirstNameString()` is better than `getTextFromField()`..